# Is there something like a "mile count" for HDDs/SSDs?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure, diagnostic

All my internal disks (3 SSDs and 1 HDD) are aging. My external USB ones (used for a complex backup scheme) are even older.

Through built-in Windows command-line mechanisms, I am able to extract an "OK" for the ones that report themselves that they work. But obviously, I would know if they don't work, so this is extremely pointless if you think about it. It's just a binary true/false, as I understand it.

What I would like to know is some sort of "percentage left" or "mile counter", which tells me how much wear and tear the disk has experienced, so that its expected expiration time can be pre-calculated.

Simply using the date they were purchased is not reliable because they have wildly different usage.

Does such a thing exist? Do HDDs/SSDs keep such a "statistic" which can be polled to usefully determine their remaining life? Anything besides this pointless "I am currently OK" signal.

Comment: I think John's answer would be good for SSDs. For HDDs, There do exist some Freeware/Paid Softs which tell you the "health" of each sector. That will also give you the count of bad sectors. This number can be said to be the measure of a HDDs wear and tear. Check out [HDDscan](https://hddscan.com/). Do read-write tests. 

"Health" of a sector actually refers to the response time of each sector. Lesser the time, better the "Health" of your HDD.

Comment: [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download) is used to garnish the S.M.A.R.T data of a drive [`smartctl -a /dev/<drvie>`], with mechanical drives measured by `Power_On_Hours` and health determined by `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`, `Offline_Uncorrectable`, hardware errors _(situated between numerical values and self-test log)_, and self-test logs _(regular short and long  S.M.A.R.T tests are recommended on mechanical drives, with a long test at least once a month)_, whereas SSDs are measured by TB written and health determined by `Wear_Leveling_Count` and `Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt`.

Comment: There isn't. Neither HDDs nor SSDs have a life rating. There might be signs, but generally any device can fail at any time.

Answer (score 2):

> Does such a thing? Do HDDs/SSDs keep such a "statistic" which can be
> polled to usefully determine their remaining life? Anything besides
> this pointless "I am currently OK" signal.

**First:** for any electronic device, Mean Time to Failure means that a given device can fail right away or last a long time.

That said, **For SSDs** (I no longer have any hard drives), a good measurement is TBW  - Number of Terabytes Written.

You need the manufacturer's estimate of SSD Life in TBW. For my Samsung 1 TB NVMe drive, the specification is 600 TBW.  This machine is a 1 TBW, my 5 year old X1 (also with a 1 TB Samsung drive) is at about 40 or so TBW after 5 years.

Also use the manufacture's S.M.A.R.T App to look for errors.

I particularly like TBW because I use Virtual Machines (disk intensive) and what I learned about my older X1 is that the drive will likely outlive the laptop.

SSDs do have a lifespan of writing to cells. At some point it can go no further. So manufacturers provide extra cells and overall lifetime. Newer High Quality SSDs have very good lifespans.

Two screen shots:

1. Lenovo Diagnostics showing TBW (and other information).
2. Samsung Magician showing Errors (none) and TBW.

[image: Lenovo Diagnostics]

.

[image: Samsung Magician]

.

**For HDDs:**  (as noted I only have SSDs now)

S.M.A.R.T can also be used on HDDs so equipped for checking for errors as in SSDs.

Power ON Hours can also be used to check life. You would need the Manufacturer's specification on what they expect.

Here is a Wiki Article on HDD checking methods.

[Power On Hours - WiKi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_hours#:%7E:text=Power%2Don%20hours%20is%20intended,43%2C800%20hours%20of%20constant%20use.)

> A part of the S.M.A.R.T. attributes (originally known as IntelliSafe,
> before its introduction to the public domain on 12 May 1995, by the
> computer hardware and software company Compaq),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92n59.png)
>
> It is used to predict drive failure, supported by manufacturers such
> as Samsung, Seagate, Toshiba, IBM (Hitachi), Fujitsu, Maxtor, Kingston
> and Western Digital.
>
> Power-on hours is intended to indicate a remaining lifetime prediction
> for hard drives and solid state drives, generally, "the total expected
> life-time of a hard disk is 5 years" [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_hours#:%7E:text=Power%2Don%20hours%20is%20intended,43%2C800%20hours%20of%20constant%20use.) or 43,800 hours of constant
> use.[4]
>
> Once a drive has surpassed the 43,800 hour mark, it may no longer be
> classed as in "perfect condition".

Comment: Don't forget power on hours for spinning drives.

Comment: I added this as best as I was able to . I no longer use hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

**SSD**

---

Unfortunately you did not mention maker and model of your SSDs!

As you were looking for "expected expiration time" there is a usage indicator available. Unfortunately this indicator does not seem to be a standard attribute that maintains the attribute number regardless of the manufacturer.

SSDs from Adata provide you with the smart attribute number
**169 Remaining_Lifetime_Perc**
I took this information from a Adata SU650 SSD.

Crucial on the other hand uses
**202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain**.

Western Digital gets awarded the most user-unfriendly representation:
**230 Media Wearout Indicator**

but this is a coded attribute that you can't simply read of a smartmontools report, you either need to decipher it or run WD Dashboard for this little piece of information.

Otherwise you could look at
**241 Host_Writes_GiB**
for WD SSDs and compare that figure with the guaranteed figure for your drive.

**HDD**

---

For HDDs there are a bunch of attributes that indicate possible issues with your drive but none of them designated a kind of wear as the ones that you find with SSDs.